# Разбиение строки на части в shell скрипте, запускаемом через jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

**Дано:**

работающий `shell` код, разбивающий строку по точке и пишущий части полученные в переменные.

```
version='1.2.3.4'

IFS='.' read -r major minor micro build <<- _EOF_
$version
_EOF_

echo $major $minor
```

**Задача:**

Использовать его в рамках `pipeline` скрипта `Jenkins`

**Проблема:**

Т.к. мне надо использовать в `shell` скрипте переменные из `pipeline` я должен обернуть `shell` код в 3 двойных кавычки. Из-за них мне надо всё подряд экранировать. И всё экранируется кроме вот этого места:

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
        sh """
        version='1.2.3.4'

        IFS='.' read -r major minor micro build <<- _EOF_
        \$version
        _EOF_

        echo \$major \$minor
        """
    }
}
```

Если экранировать так: `\$version` - происходит попытка чтения `pipline` переменной и падение. Если начать как-то извращаться - лезут уж совсем странные ошибки типа `unexpected end of file`

**Вопрос:**

Как тут надо сделать? И почему проблема именно тут? У меня вообще довольно много там кода, но экранирование не работает именно тут

Comment: сочетание двух разных типов heredoc — в shell и ещё в чём-нибудь  — сочетание довольно хрупкое и капризное. вынести код в отдельный файл проблематично?

Comment: кстати, от shell-овского heredoc-а несложно избавиться: `echo 1.2.3.4 | { IFS=. read k l m n; echo $k $l; }`. скобки — существенны для видимости переменных.

Comment: При написании в блоке `sh` `$version` будет произведено чтение переменной из Pipeline, a `\$version` экранирует переменную, объявленную в `sh`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ура! Это работает! Спасибо! Вы мой герой! И как моего героя хочу вас спросить только лишь об одном  - как мне теперь эти переменные за пределами фигурных скобок получить для обращения к ним? =)

Comment: @FCh, да, это я уже понял) Проблема в том, что `\$version` вызывает падение с `unexpected end of file`

Comment: Задал дополнительный вопрос по поводу фигурных скобок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769027/17609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что перед последовательностью символов, завершающих *heredoc*, должны быть только табуляторы (`0х09`), и наких пробелов, ни перед, ни после. Подробнее [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776287/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-heredoc-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-delimited-by-end-of-file/776291#776291). О том, что редакторы могут заменять вводимые символы табуляции пробелами, см., например, [связанный с ним вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776458/vim-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-expandtab?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Чтобы не заботится об отступпах, можно просто удалить отступы методом [stripIndent()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#stripIndent()).
Фрагмент кода из вопроса будет выглядеть так:

```sh
stage('test') {
    steps {
        sh """
        version='1.2.3.4'

        IFS='.' read -r major minor micro build <<- _EOF_
            \$version
        _EOF_
        echo \$major \$minor
        """.stripIndent()
    }
}
```

PS этот ответ касается только "красоты" кода, о целесообразности здесь *heredoc* уже подробно отвечено в [комментарии @alexanderbarakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768868/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-shell-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-jenkins-pipeline#comment1198238_768868).

Answer (score 0):

В итоге проблема оказалась в пробелах и табах, с помощью которых код станавится читаемым и красивым. Если код изуродовать так(убрав отступы):

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
sh """
version='1.2.3.4'

IFS=. read a b c d <<EOF
\$version
EOF

echo \"a\" \$a \"b\" \$b \"c\" \$c \"d\" \$d
"""
    }
}
```

то всё отлично работает. Вывод - всё очень плохо. Любая строчка кода на `shell` стреляет программисту в ногу с вероятностью около 87%.

Comment: Если нужны отступы с heredoc то - `<<-eof`, правда работет только с табами, с пробелами нет.

Comment: @0xdb, не помогло( Поставил табы, поменял `EOF` на `-eof` - падает с руганью на неожиданный конец файла(

Comment: А так -EOF? Это не важно eof, EOF, XYZ или xxx, главное и в начале и в конце должны полностью совпадать включая регистр.

Comment: @0xdb, не-а, не работает(

Comment: Странно, у меня тоже по быстрому не получилось, а ведь когда-то делал. Из мануала - If  the  redirection  operator  is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents  within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Comment: У меня заработало, был пробел после конечного eof, т.е "eof "

Comment: @0xdb, у меня опыт в `shell` 3 дня, но я уже его ненавижу) 3 дня убил на код, который читает файл, отправляет его содержимое яндексу, а ответ пишет в несколько файлов, имя которых составляет из версии приложения в `properties` файле. Реально каждое действие - головная боль. Массивов, например, в чистом `shell` нет, простого чтения пропертей - нет... И всё это ещё экранировать надо в моём случае. Одна только нужда в `if`-е пробелы выставить внутри скобок похитила у мня час времени( А ошибки выдаёт, кажется, вообще наобум(((

Comment: О, сейчас попробую

Comment: @0xdb, у меня всё ещё не работает - вроде всё верно, ничего лишнего, но не хочет. Хм... Кажется, у меня табы в пробелы редактор превращает...

Comment: Понимаю, ну это же не сов сем ЯП, это командный интерпретатор. Да, нужен действительно табулятор, некоторые редакторы клавишу табулятор заменяют на несколько пробелов.  И eof в конце без "-".

Comment: @0xdb, ох, жесть... Ладно, чёрт с ним, с форматированием) Всё равно код никто не увидит - не охота возиться теперь ещё и с тем, чтобы руками в блокноте написанный код подключать и всякие там переменные в него прокидывать и извлекать потом)

Comment: Хорошо. Время появится, я посмотрю ещё раз. Если не сейчас, то на будующее пригодится.

Comment: Наверное уже не актуально, тогда хотел воизпроизвести, не получилось, т.к. нет jenkins под рукой.  Не знаю как его pipeline симулировать.

Comment: @0xdb, ну, вообще да - уже не очень актуально. Сейчас и так работает) Потом перепишу на `groovy` - c ним всё намного проще)

Comment: Хорошо, с  groovy будет попроще. Просто  в очереди проверок [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776287/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-heredoc-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-delimited-by-end-of-file) на эту тему проскачил, вспомнил.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так:

```
node {
  sh """echo -e "sqlplus ${dbuser}/${dbpass}@test << EOF
    select * from dual;
  EOF
  " > test.sh
  """
  sh "bash -vx test.sh"
}
```