# Как получить доступ к значению переменной, созданной внутри фигурных скобок в shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

**Дано:**

Код, разбивающий строку по точке и складывающий полученные части в переменные.

```
sh """
version='1.2.3.4'

echo \$version | { IFS=. read a b c d; echo \$a; }

echo \"a\" \$a
"""
```

При запуске получаем вот это:

```
+ version=1.2.3.4
+ IFS=. read a b c d
+ echo 1.2.3.4
+ echo 1
1
+ echo a
a
```

**Проблема:**

Из-за фигурных скобок переменные, в которых лежит нужные значения, недоступны.

**Вопрос:**

Каким образом получить значения переменных `a, b, c, d` за пределами фигурных скобок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы не прочитать сразу все значения в массив:

```
IFS='.' read -r -a arr <<< "${version}"
```

Результат:

```
[ ~]# echo ${arr[@]}
1 2 3 4   
[ ~]# echo ${arr[0]}
1
[ ~]# echo ${arr[1]}
2
[ ~]# echo ${arr[2]}
3
[ ~]# echo ${arr[3]}
4
```

или так:

```
IFS='.' read -r -a a b c d <<< "${version}"
```

Comment: К сожалению, в моём случае это не работает. Толи у вас тут код для `bash` а у меня просто `shell`. А может, дело в том, что у меня этот код находится внутри `pipeline` `jenkins`-а, и я вынужден всё подряд экранировать. Ваш код в моём случае падает или с `Syntax error: redirection unexpected` при попытке экранирования, или пытается искать `version` во вне `shell` скрипта - `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: version for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: Ранее у меня была [другая версия этого кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768868/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-shell-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-jenkins-pipeline?noredirect=1&lq=1), но она не работала в указанном выше окружении. В итоге заработала только версия с фигурными скобками. Я уже готов сдаться и писать переменные в файлы и их оттуда потом считывать(((

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а можно это как-то протестировать без Jenkins?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а в какой shell у вас?

Comment: Без `jenkins` работают все варианты) С ним - только тот, что в вопросе( Версия - `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: В итоге использовал вариант из ответа по первому вопросу. Там проблема в итоге была в том, что скрипту мешали отступы. Хотя в сообщениях об ошибке этого не было. В итоге код уродливый, но работает)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте **declare** или **eval**

```
~$ declare $(echo 1.2.3.4 | awk -F. '{print "a="$1,"b="$2,"c="$3,"d="$4}')
~$ export a b c d              
~$ echo $b                     
2
```

Вариант опробован на мобилном **bash**

```
~$ echo $0
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
```

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505026/set-variable-in-current-shell-from-awk

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня ошибку выдаёт: `declare: not found`. Попробовал прописать в начале `#!/bin/bash` - не помогает