# Вывод орератором heredoc с ошибкой - delimited by end-of-file

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

Прочитал в мануале:

> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. 
>   This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

То есть с оператором `<<-` можно добавлять табулятором отступы в here-document.

Пробую:

```
#!/bin/bash
    cat <<-EOF
        first line
        last  line
    EOF
```

Выводит:

```
')tstheredoc: line 5: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF
        first line
        last  line
    EOF
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой вид heredoc удаляет только табуляции, но не пробелы. Такая же ошибка может появляться, если перед EOF стоят какие либо символы (по правилам он должен быть в самом начале строки), отличные от табуляции. Скорее всего у вас перед EOF стоят пробелы, а не табуляции.

```
 #!/bin/bash
    cat <<-EOF
        first line
        last  line
 <тут-обязательно-табуляции>EOF
```

Comment: @simpleCode У меня кстати была та же проблема с редактором, я когда проверял, в данных то явно табуляции поставил (потому что увидел, что они остались в выводе), а перед EOF забыл попробовать :) Поправил.

Comment: Да, я еще вчера в vi добавил <C-V><Tab> и заработало. Спасибо за помощь, отличный ответ.