# Vim превратил табулатор в пробелы после отключения expandtab

Tags: linux, vim

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776287/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-heredoc-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-delimited-by-end-of-file) я спрашивал про одну ошибку. Причиной ошибки оказалось, что вместо 
табулятора ввелись пробелы.

Я выполнил в *viм* - `:set noexpandtab`, чтобы не было пробелов.
Ввёл клавишей табулятор и затем EOF.

А в файле после сохранения действительно пробелы:

```
~$ xd tabs
000000 20 20 20 20 45 4f 46 0d 0a                       > EOF..<
```

Устранил ошибку с <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Почему *viм* превратил табулятор в пробелы после `noexpandtab`?

Comment: Есть уверенность, что это был именно vim, а не какой-нибудь инструмент, который причёсывает код в соответствии с гайдлайнами?

Comment: @AK. Да,  есть. Даже до сохранения нового файла, т.е. плагины отключены, там пробелы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае просто получился такой вариант: softwidth < tabstop. Смотрите!

На ввод пробельных символов (которые обычно отображатся в виде пропуска в
тексте) клавишей <kbd>TAB</kbd> в Vim влияют упомянутый вами параметр
expandtab, но также softwidth и tabstop следующим образом. При активированном
noexpandtab (это ваш случай) при нажатии на клавишу табуляции редактор
вычисляет ближайшую позицию для вставляемого *отступа*, которой задаётся
настройкой softwidth, затем вставляет столько символов табуляции, чтобы не
выйти за новую рассчитанную позицию курсора, считая при этом `'\t'` (U+0009)
по ширине эквивалентным tabstop пробелам. Остальное пространство заполняется
обычными пробелами.

Возможно, это выглядит слишком замудрёно, но рассмотрим пример. Допустим,
softwidth=2, tabstop=4, ваш редактор находится в режиме вставки, а курсор
стоит в начале строки (в колонке №1). Вы нажимаете на клавиатуре клавишу
<kbd>TAB</kbd> и вставляются два обычных пробела `' '` (U+0020), а курсор
переходит в колонку №3. Вы второй раз нажимаете на табуляцию — эти пробелы
заменяются на одну `'\t'` (курсор в 4 колонке). Нажмите в третий раз —
получите одну табуляцию, а за ней два пробела (теперь курсор в 6 колонке).
Четвёртое нажатие приведёт к вводу двух символов табуляции и т.д.

Иными словами, нажатие <kbd>TAB</kbd> заставляет редактор увеличить *отступ*
курсора на единицу, но ширина одного отступа задаётся настройкой softwidth. А
ширина одного символа табуляции настраивается с помощью tabstop.

Поэкспериментируйте с конфигурацией Vim, а легко различать табулиции `'\t'` от
пробелов `' '` вам поможет примерно такая команда для подсветки пробельных
символов.

```
set list lcs=tab:>\ ,space:.
```

Comment: Точно, попробовал,  помогло. Только у меня почему то так заработало `:set tabstop=4`, было 8. А tabspace вообще такого нету. Разница в версиях?

Comment: это я перепутал - поправил

Comment: Здорово,  а то я уже смотрю по всем машинам - что там.